# Java Code check fields in duplicate, when value change start again

Tags: java

I want to write small java program to read data file first field and add seqcution number

Input file:

```
robert,190 vikign,...
robert,2401 windy,...
robert,1555 oakbrook,...
michell,2524 sprint,...
michell,1245 oakbrrok,...
xyz,2455 xyz drive,....
```

Output file should be:

```
robert,190 vikign,...,0
robert,2401 windy,...,1
robert,1555 oakbrook,...,2
michell,2524 sprint,...,0
michell,1245 oakbrrok,...,1
xyz,2455 xyz drive,....,0
```

Check first field when value change sequction number start back to 0 otherwise add sequction number by 1

here is my code:

```
public static void createseq(String str) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        BufferedWriter bfAllBWP = null;

        File folderall = new File("Sort_Data_File_Out");
        File[] BFFileall = folderall.listFiles();

        for (File file : BFFileall) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String bwp = "FinalDataFileOut\\" + str;
            bfAllBWP = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(bwp));

            String line;
            line = br.readLine();
            String[] actionID = line.split("\\|");

            String fullname = actionID[0].trim();
            int seq = 0;
            String fullnameb;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                actionID = line.split("\\|");
                fullnameb = actionID[0].trim();

                if(fullname.equals(fullnameb)) {
                    seq++;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(line + "======" + seq + "\n");
                    seq = 0;
                    fullname = fullnameb;
                }
                System.out.println("dshgfsdj "+line + "======" + seq + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception letterproof) {
        letterproof.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it not working correctly?

Comment: it giving me wrong output, please help me, I know, my code it not correct.. is there anyother way that i can do that.. Please help me, thanks in advanced!!

Comment: @user3187463 - Is the value of `seq` being set correctly when you step through your code?

Comment: seq number it should be 0, if its same than increase by 1 and else condition just print 0.. Please help me thanks!! I think something wrong with my if condition.. please help me, Thanks in advaced!!

Comment: @user3187463 Given there seems to be *no* value of `seq` in your output, can you show us exactly what the value of `seq` is when you step through your code?

Comment: I'm confused by your split regex - unless you've got different input data than you're indicating, that isn't splitting anything out.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, its just give me wrong output, I have no idea why its not working, because of line or if condition else DO i have put system.out.println() statement inside if condition??

Comment: ya, in original file split regex is | not , sorry about that,

Comment: I would suggest to use awk instead of java to process text files, there is jawk too (awk implementation for java)http://jawk.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will fix the issue.I have updated the code if you face any pblm plz let me know :

Input :

```
robert,190 vikign,...
robert,2401 windy,...
robert,1555 oakbrook,...
michell,2524 sprint,...
michell,1245 oakbrrok,...
xyz,2455 xyz drive,....
```

Code :

```
public static void createseq() {

    try {

        File file = new File("d:\\words.txt"); //Hardcoded file for testing locally
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        HashMap<String,Integer> counter = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String line;

           while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
           {
               String[] actionID = line.split(",");
               String firstName = actionID[0];

                 if(counter.containsKey(firstName))
                 {
                     counter.put(firstName, counter.get(firstName) + 1);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     counter.put(firstName,0);
                 }
               System.out.println(line+" "+counter.get(firstName));
           }
          br.close();
    } catch(Exception letterproof) {
         letterproof.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Ouput Come :

```
robert,190 vikign,... 0
robert,2401 windy,... 1
robert,1555 oakbrook,... 2
michell,2524 sprint,... 0
michell,1245 oakbrrok,... 1
xyz,2455 xyz drive,.... 0
```

Comment: @user3187463 found the answer

Comment: Thank you so much, its working, I want ask you one more question what about, its not in sorting format, still it will work??